# How to unselect a default version for "Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, azure-devops

I cannot for the life of me figure this out right now. You would think this would be easy, but no. It is not so easy.

**Issue:**

I was trying to use VSTS's (Visual Studio Team Services) clone feature to clone a repository. Clicked the button when viewed on the web through a chrome browser.

Visual studio version selector popped up and asked me which version of VS I wanted to use to clone the repository.I accidentally clicked on version 2017, and then checked the "remember" my choice option. Now I can't figure out how to undo that decision.

I am trying to open this operation using VS2015 instead.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I tried searching for answers on other posts. No one seems to have created a post for this issue yet.

Comment: And you can also try to clean the cookies and caches on the bower you are using to check if the selector dialog can display again.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this by changing the default protocol VSWEB on Windows 10 settings.
In my case I have both VS 2017 and 2019 and clicking on clone in Visual Studio opened VS2017 and I wanted 2019.
Steps:

*(Options may not be exactly the same because my Windows 10 is the Spanish version and I am translating)*

1. Go to Windows Settings (Click in notifications on lower-right and
   select All Settings).
2. Go to Applications
3. Select *Default Applications* on left hand menu.
4. Scroll to the bottom, you Will see something like "choose default
   application by protocol", again not sure what the exact English
   title Will be.
5. There look for VSWEB protocol handler and change it.

At least on my PC there were two identical options (not very helpful): the first one was for VS 2017 and the second for VS 2019, but I had to try them both to find out.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **Clone in Visual Studio** button to clone git repo in VSTS, **Microsoft visual studio web protocol handler selector** will choose the latest version you installed. So you can’t make it choose VS2015 after you've installed VS2017.

The common way is to **clone git repo from VSTS directory by VS**. You can open VS2015 -> Team Exporler -> Manage connections -> connect to team project -> add your VSTS as a server -> select the project you want to connect -> connect -> right click the project -> clone.

Now that it's cloned locally, and you can work with it on VS2015. More detail you can refer [clone a repo](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/clone#clone-a-repo).

Comment: it is choosing 2017 for me while I have 2019 Preview installed.